# C++ Winforms: Why doesn't the richtextbox update text instantly?

Tags: c++, winforms, richtextbox

I've written a PC application using Winforms/C++. I'm trying to get some data from an external EEPROM into my PC, I do this when I click a button on my Winforms Application. The downloading takes a lot of time to complete so I have a textbox where I kinda of indicate to the user by first displaying "***Downloading Voltage fluctuation data. Please wait...***", then I call the function which starts downloading the data(Takes about 30 seconds), finally I print a "***done!***".

But the problem I'm facing is that my first line "***Downloading Voltage fluctuation data. Please wait...***" is not displayed instantly it gets displayed along with "***done!***" only after **30 seconds**, which is not serving the purpose.

I'm not new to C++ but this is **my first attempt to make use of WinForms**, so I don't know what I should do to bring the text up instantly.

**Is there a function to flush the text to the richtextbox, explicitly?**

My code for the button is as below.

```
private: System::Void button4_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
     {

        this->richTextBox1->Text += "\n> Downloading Voltage fluctuation data...";

        Download_EEPROM_data();

        this->richTextBox1->Text += " done!";
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because the update happens next time your program runs its event handling loop. And since you block that with a lengthy function call it doesn't happen.

One possible solution is to use a separate thread to do the downloading, and that thread notifies the main GUI thread of it's status.

Answer (score 2):

You will see update once button4_Click(...) returns as currently Download_EEPROM_data() call is blocking it. You can use a separate thread which download the data from eeprom and as done inform the main thread and it can post "done" message.